# Github commit from VSCode has no profile icon

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, avatar

When committing to Github directly from VSCode (Visual Studio code),
my github profile **user icon is not visible in the commit history on Github**.

Eg.
[image]

There is no avatar shown for my user, while I do have one set on the Github website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because your email address is not properly registered inside your computer's git config.

You can set it like so (globally):

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

Or locally per repository, execute this inside the directory:

```
git config user.email "email@example.com"
```

Then your icon will show up again!